# Nativescript iOS questions on info.plist

Tags: nativescript

In the info.plist file, I see $(PRODUCT_NAME) and $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) - where are these names derived from.

Also, is there a way for me to get the Bundle version at run-time from within the app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the bundle version you can use the nativescript-appversion plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-appversion

Comment: This unfortunately only answer to the side question. Still wondering from where $(PRODUCT_NAME) and $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) are derived from.